# Get the label value of option in selectbox using selectbox name and set it as new value of heading Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to javascript I am trying to get the value of the label of select box by using selectbox name not its id then set the value I got as my new heading however my code below is not giving my desired output it changed my heading 01 when chose january because i am getting value I want it to be january. I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <h3 id = "p2">I will change this part</h3>

    <script>
        var x = document.getElementsByName("start_month")[0].value;
        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = x
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

my select box is

```
 <select id="month3781857" name="start_month"    >
     <option value="01" grouping=""  >January</option>
     <option value="02" grouping=""  >February</option>
     <option value="03" grouping=""  >March</option>
     <option value="04" grouping=""  >April</option>
     <option value="05" grouping=""  >May</option>
     <option value="06" grouping=""  >June</option>
     <option value="07" grouping=""  >July</option>
     <option value="08" grouping=""  >August</option>
     <option value="09" grouping=""  >September</option>
     <option value="10" grouping=""  >October</option>
     <option value="11" grouping=""  >November</option>
     <option value="12" grouping=""  >December</option>
</select>
```

like if I select january the value I want my header to have january

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an event listener for when the user makes their selection from the selection list. You can then populate your header with the text from the option selected. Ordinarily, you would simply use the select item's value for this, but you had these set to months as numbers. So instead of having to translate these into month names, I've just used the options text instead:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByName("start_month")[0];

function start() {
  x.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
  });
}

window.load = start();
```

```html
<h3 id="p2">I will change this part</h3>
<select id="month3781857" name="start_month">
  <option value="" grouping=""></option>
  <option value="01" grouping="">January</option>
  <option value="02" grouping="">February</option>
  <option value="03" grouping="">March</option>
  <option value="04" grouping="">April</option>
  <option value="05" grouping="">May</option>
  <option value="06" grouping="">June</option>
  <option value="07" grouping="">July</option>
  <option value="08" grouping="">August</option>
  <option value="09" grouping="">September</option>
  <option value="10" grouping="">October</option>
  <option value="11" grouping="">November</option>
  <option value="12" grouping="">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you its working really appreciate your help and time

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for getting the `text` property of the selected item using the selectedIndex and setting that to the innerHTML of the `<h3>` by id.

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("start_month")[0];
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
```

If you want to update it when you change the selection you could create a function for onchange or attach an event handler:

```js
function updateValue() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("start_month")[0];
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="p2">I will change this part</h3>
<select id="month3781857" name="start_month" onchange="updateValue()">
  <option value="01" grouping="">January</option>
  <option value="02" grouping="">February</option>
  <option value="03" grouping="">March</option>
  <option value="04" grouping="">April</option>
  <option value="05" grouping="">May</option>
  <option value="06" grouping="">June</option>
  <option value="07" grouping="">July</option>
  <option value="08" grouping="">August</option>
  <option value="09" grouping="">September</option>
  <option value="10" grouping="">October</option>
  <option value="11" grouping="">November</option>
  <option value="12" grouping="">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you its also working really appreciate your help and time

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change the content of your `h3` or any dom element by using Javascript or jQuery. I see a Javascript solution has already been provided so here is my jQuery solution.

```js
$('#month3781857').change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $('#p2').text(str);
  }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="month3781857" name="start_month">
 <option value="01" grouping=""  >January</option>
 <option value="02" grouping=""  >February</option>
 <option value="03" grouping=""  >March</option>
 <option value="04" grouping=""  >April</option>
 <option value="05" grouping=""  >May</option>
 <option value="06" grouping=""  >June</option>
 <option value="07" grouping=""  >July</option>
 <option value="08" grouping=""  >August</option>
 <option value="09" grouping=""  >September</option>
 <option value="10" grouping=""  >October</option>
 <option value="11" grouping=""  >November</option>
 <option value="12" grouping=""  >December</option>
</select>

<h3 id="p2">I will change this part</h3>
```

Comment: thank you its working really appreciate your help and time

Comment: @aikaaika no problem!

Answer (score -1):

Use

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Or look this https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1603881-apprenez-a-creer-votre-site-web-avec-html5-et-css3/1607171-les-formulaires.
it's in french but it can help you

date: for the date (05/08/1985 for exemple) 
time: for time (13:37 for exemple) 
week: for the week 
month: for the month 
datetime: date and hours auto 
datetime-local date ans hours with jet lag